# How do I set Ubuntu Bold Font as the window titlebar font?

Tags: fonts, window, titlebar, ubuntu-font-family

I've made a fresh Ubuntu 12.10 install and the Ubuntu Bold font is missing from the font selection screens.

This means that if I try to use Ubuntu Tweak to set the title font for windows as "Ubuntu Bold" it does not appear as a choice.

The actual file is present in `/usr/share`. If I use the font in Writer, for example, I can set it to bold without issues.

I've tried `fc-cache -frv` but that's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came back to post a solution that worked for me. If the Ubuntu Bold font does not appear the the selection list, use the following command to set it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font "Ubuntu Bold 9"
```

Credit here: http://podzemski.com/2012/10/20/ubuntu-12-10-font-siz/